# Make a Plain PIE!

Tags: math, number, code-challenge

**(2 Jan 2018) Because of the winning criteria I am going to accept the Jelly answer, but I am also giving upvotes to all other answers which all use astounding methods as well**

### Introduction

There are lots of challenges asking for a shortest program to calculate mathematical constants. I saw some with restrictions like banning the literals 3.14 and π etc. However, there seems no such challenges using the number of distinct characters as one of the criteria.

### The Challenge

<s>Make a Plain PIE using the fewest kinds and least amount of ingredients but still yummy enough</s>

Write a code that calculates π*e to at least 10 decimal places, that uses as *FEW* distinct characters (and de facto numeric literal characters) and as short as possible.

This challenge is not banning numeric literals; instead they are discouraged. Numeric literals are *seasonings* ;)

### Requirements

- The code must be a full program receiving no inputs and outputting the result, or a function which can be called with no arguments either outputting or returning the result. Lambdas are allowed.
- The result must start with `8.5397342226` and must be in a *numeric type*. There should only be one output/return in the main program/function. Sub-functions are allowed.

### Restrictions

- String-to-number conversion functions *that trivially turn the string literal to a number it represents* are not allowed unless explicitly declared and implemented within the code. Also, *NO implicit conversions from strings to numbers*.

  - eg. `eval`, `Number()`, `parseInt()` and `"string" * 1`
  - Character-code functions and length functions like `ord`, `String.charCodeAt(n)` and `String.length` are allowed because they do not trivially convert the string into the corresponding number.
- Use of the following built-ins are not allowed:

  - Mathematical constants, or any built-in functions that evaluates to those constants directly

    - eg. `Math.PI` in JS, `žs` in 05AB1E (because it evaluates to π directly)
  - Trigonometric functions and the exponential function, unless explicitly defined and implemented in the code.

    - eg. `Math.atan` and `Math.exp` in JS
    - Built-in power functions and exponentiation operators (eg. ** or ^) are allowed, given that they receive 2 arguments/operands (WLOG `a` and `b`) and returns a<sup>b</sup>
- The length of each run of numeric literal used must not be longer than 5 (eg. `12345` allowed (but not encouraged), but `123456` is not allowed).
- Standard loopholes apply.

### Scoring

- The scoring is divided into three parts:

  - **Distinctness**: Scored by counting the number of distinct characters used. Uppercase and lowercase are counted separately. However, the following characters must each be counted as 10 characters:

    - Hexadecimal digits: `0123456789abcdefABCDEF`
    - Decimal points: `.`
    - Any other single characters that may be used as numeric literals (applicable in golfing languages)
  - **Size**: Scored by the length of the code in bytes.
  - **Accuracy**: Scored by the number of correct digits counting from the decimal point. Any digits after the first wrong digit are not counted. For fairness, a maximum of 15 digits are counted. The value of π*e according to WolframAlpha is `8.539734222673567(06546...)`.
- The total score is calculated by `(Distinctness * Size) / Accuracy`

### Winning Criteria

The answer with the lowest score wins. If tied then the candidate answer which is posted earlier wins.

For non-golfing languages, the score can be calculated using the following snippet (For some golfing languages, the snippet does not work since this checks for UTF-8 length of the code only):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 $("#calculate").on("click", () => {
  var count = {};
  var distinct = 0;
  var nonnums = 0;
  var numerals = 0;
  var length = 0;
  for (const c of [...$("#code").val()]) {
   count[c]++;
   if (c.charCodeAt(0) <= 0x7F)
    length += 1;
   else if (c.charCodeAt(0) <= 0x3FF)
    length += 2;
   else if (c.charCodeAt(0) >= 0xD800 && c.charCodeAt(0) <= 0xDFFF)
    length += 4;
   else
    length += 3; 
  }
  for (const c in count) {
   if ("0123456789abcdefABCDEF.".indexOf(c) == -1) {
    nonnums += 1;
    distinct += 1;
   }
   else {
    numerals += 1;
    distinct += 10;
   }
  }
  
  var output = $("#output").val();
  var match = /^8\.(5397342226(7(3(5(67?)?)?)?)?)/.exec(output);
  if (match == null)
   $("#result").html("The result does not have 10-digit accuracy!");
  else {
   var accuracy = match[1].length;
   $("#result").html(`
    Size        : ${length} bytes<br>
    Distinctness: ${distinct} (Numerals: ${numerals}, Non-numerals: ${nonnums})<br>
    Accuracy    : ${accuracy} decimal places<br>
    Score       : ${(distinct * length / accuracy).toFixed(2)}
   `);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Calculator for Non-esoteric Programming Languages (BASIC-like, C-like, Python, Ruby, etc.)</h2>
Code: <br><textarea cols=50 rows=10 id="code"></textarea><br>
Output: <input id="output"><br>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate Score">
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

### Example

**Submission**

## JavaScript(ES6), S=141, D=49, A=12, 575.75pt

```
(t=()=>{for(f=o=9/9;++o<9999;)f+=o**-(9>>9/9);return (f*(9*9+9))**(9/9/(9>>9/9))},u=()=>{for(f=o=r=9/9;++o<99;){f+=r;r/=o}return f})=>t()*u()
```

Output: `8.53973422267302`

**Scoring**

```
Size        : 141 bytes
Distinctness: 49 (Numerals: 3 (use of "9", "e" and "f")), Non-numerals: 19)
Accuracy    : 12 decimal places
Score       : 575.75
```

Comment: [tag:code-challenge] because [tag:code-golf] is specifically for challenges where the sole scoring consideration is number of bytes for the interpreter to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Thank you for the reminder, the clarification and the edit ;)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "must be a numerical type"? Also, this prevents certain languages from participating so I'd recommend you consider removing that (somewhat vague) restriction.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14382).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I would say the phrase is to prevent codes which output of the string "8.5397342226..." directly (especially output digit by digit). I am expecting the calculation of the value.

Comment: @user71546 That does stop a couple of languages from participating where math isn't really a thing, but it's up to you to decide; those languages could offer something creative or interesting but it might also make the challenge less interesting in the long run. Up to you to decide of course!

Comment: @WheatWizard Thank you for the question. I have added some examples and clarified that chararcter-code extraction functions and length functions like `ord` and `String.length` are permitted because it does not trivially convert the string literal into a number.

Comment: There's a slightly-more-competitive-than-usual Unary answer out there...

Comment: Your question should include the actual value of πe to 15 digits.

Comment: I secretly hoped that this question would involve the Proto-Indo-European language in some way :(

Comment: @Lynn Added the actual value to `Scoring > Accuracy`. The actual value to 15 dp has been in the snippet code, inside the regex, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 × 38 ÷ 10 = 41.8

```
“Þẹjuụ’÷ȷ10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4oCcw57hurlqdeG7peKAmcO3yLcxMP//)

## Explanation

```
“Þẹjuụ’÷ȷ10  Main Link
“Þẹjuụ’      85397342226
       ÷     Divided by
        ȷ10  1e10
```

Comment: Since `ȷ` can be used as `1000` if used separately, I will count it as a single-character numeric literal :)

Comment: BTW `“` seems to mark a string literal. The answer is invalid if built-in or implicit string-to-number conversion is used as per restrictions.

Comment: @user71546 Is built-in integer compression forbidden then? That should be specified separately because in this case `“` denotes a number literal, not a string literal.

Comment: `11 × 101 ÷ 10 = 111.1`. Works in binary too!

Comment: @JungHwanMin Hm interesting! I wonder, does that work for the general case? I'd think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: never mind `11*11=121` but `11*11=1001`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino should work for any base, since in base `x`, the expression is `(x + 1)(x^2 + 1)/x == x^2 + x + 1 + 1/x`, which is true for nonzero `x`.

Comment: @JungHwanMin That's true. I was actually talking not about which base but rather the specific digits, but then I counter-exampled myself :P But hm interesting, you're right in every base it should work.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I would say this is a special case that I missed because the literal does not end with `”` so it does not contribute to be a string.

Comment: Btw the first 7 characters are only counted as 10 each if they can be used separately as a numeric literal, so the score can be lower.

Comment: @user71546 Oh cool, thanks for specifying!

Comment: Hm, I don't know if `“Þẹjuụ’` is valid, since one may say that it's a numeric literal, since you don't use any other functions to obtain the number from it. Another opinion would however be that this is a string that isn't directly converted to an integer but decompressed, so, in that case, it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The OP's comments seem to indicate that I can count it as regular characters because none of the characters can be used as a numerical literal on its own, and since it's decompression, it doesn't count in this case.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, (18*226)/15 = 271

only 1s

```
N[1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1/(1+1/(1+1/(1+1+1+1+1+1/(1+1/(1+1+1+1/(1+1/(1+1+1+1+1/(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1/(1+1+1+1/(1+1+1/(1+1/(1+1+1+1+1+1/(1+1+1/(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1/(1+1/(1+1)))))))))))))))),1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y/aUBsN6mugEJjC2ljkUZRiMQ@JgcNowmaACU00oINTDwTG/g8oyswrcUj7DwA)

## Mathematica, 244

1s & 2s

```
N[2+2+2+2+1/(1+1/(1+1/(1+2+2+1/(1+1/(1+2+1/(1+1/(2+2+1/(12+1/(1+2+1/(2+1/(1+1/(1+2+2+1/(2+1/(12+1/(1+1/(1+1)))))))))))))))),12+2+2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y/aSBsCDfU1DJEIVCEEGyZuhCRhhKkPRRGE0EQDOoZgi2P/BxRl5pU4pP0HAA)

Comment: WOW, only 1s and 6s. btw the parentheses surrouding 6-1 can be removed for -4 bytes

Comment: updated. only 1s

Comment: Quick explanation: Continued fraction approach.

Comment: you people are mind-meltingly clever!!! it makes me angry at myself!!

Comment: For what it’s worth, this translates to `1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1÷1+1÷1+1÷1+1+1+1+1+1÷1+1÷1+1+1+1÷1+1÷1+1+1+1+1÷1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1÷1+1+1+1÷1+1+1÷1+1÷1+1+1+1+1+1÷1+1+1÷1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1÷1+1÷1+1` in APL, scoring `12×159÷15 = 127.2` points.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 257.6

```
N[2Integrate[Sqrt[1-n^2],{n,-1,1}],22]Sum[1/n!,{n,0,22}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y/ayDOvJDW9KLEkNTq4sKgk2lA3L84oVqc6T0fXUMewNlbHyCg2uDQ32lA/TxEkagAUqI39H1CUmVfikPYfAA)

## Mathematica, 276

this is accurate to **4095 digits**

```
N[2Integrate[Sqrt[1-n^2],{n,-1,1}],2^12]Sum[1/n!,{n,0,2^12}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y/ayDOvJDW9KLEkNTq4sKgk2lA3L84oVqc6T0fXUMewNlbHKM7QKDa4NDfaUD9PESRuABaqjf0fUJSZV@KQ9h8A)

Comment: Would it save any points to replace `1/n!` with `n!^-1`?

Comment: no... it is (69*60)/15=276 (this one) vs (68*61)/15=276.533 (yours)

Answer (score 3):

## [Imperative Tampio](https://github.com/fergusq/tampio), 2206.46

```
K:lla on h:t.K:n z on riippuen siitä,onko sen h:iden määrä nolla,joko nolla tai sen ensimmäinen h lisättynä uuden K:n,jonka h:t ovat sen h:t toisesta alkaen eikä muuta,z:aan jaettuna kymmenellä.Kun iso sivu avautuu,se näyttää uuden K:n,jonka h:ita ovat kolme lisättynä viiteen,viisi,kolme,neljä lisättynä viiteen,7,kolme,neljä,kaksi,kaksi,kaksi,kuusi,7,kolme,viisi ja 7 eikä muuta,z:n.
```

> K:lla **on** h:t.K:n z **on** **riippuen** **siitä**,**onko** sen h:iden määrä `nolla`,**joko** `nolla` **tai** sen `ensimmäinen` h **lisättynä** **uuden** K:n,**jonka** h:t **ovat** sen h:t `toisesta` **alkaen** **eikä** **muuta**,z:aan **jaettuna** `kymmenellä`.**Kun** iso sivu *avautuu*,se *näyttää* **uuden** K:n,**jonka** h:ita **ovat** `kolme` **lisättynä** `viiteen`,`viisi`,`kolme`,`neljä` **lisättynä** `viiteen`,`7`,`kolme`,`neljä`,`kaksi`,`kaksi`,`kaksi`,`kuusi`,`7`,`kolme`,`viisi` **ja** `7` **eikä** **muuta**,z:n.

[Online version](http://iikka.kapsi.fi/tampio/pie.html)

Tampio has an advantage that number literals can be written using letters instead of digits. I also noticed that the interpreter thinks that one-letter words are nouns, so I can use them as identifiers. Of course, this language is so verbose that it won't help it to win any challenge.

Ungolfed:

> Listalla **on** alkiot.
>
> Listan lukuarvo **on**
>       **riippuen** **siitä**, **onko** sen alkioiden määrä `nolla`,
>
> - **joko** `nolla`
> - **tai** sen `ensimmäinen` alkio **lisättynä** **uuden** listan, **jonka** alkiot **ovat** sen alkiot `toisesta` **alkaen** **eikä** **muuta**, lukuarvoon **jaettuna** `kymmenellä`.
>
> **Kun** nykyinen sivu *avautuu*,
>
> - se *näyttää* **uuden** listan, **jonka** alkioita **ovat** `8`,`5`,`3`,`9`,`7`,`3`,`4`,`2`,`2`,`2`,`6`,`7`,`3`,`5` **ja** `7` **eikä** **muuta**, lukuarvon.

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 6×124÷15 = 49.6 points

```
zz+zz+zz+zz+÷z+÷z+÷z+zz+zz+÷z+÷z+zz+÷z+÷zz+zz+÷zz+zz+zz+zz+zz+zz+÷z+zz+÷zz+÷z+÷z+zz+zz+÷zz+÷zz+zz+zz+zz+zz+zz+÷z+÷zz←z+z←⍴⍴⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/) (Paste in the code then hit Ctrl+Enter.)

Assigns `1` to `z`, then abbreviates `z+z` to `zz`, and then approximates the [continued fraction of `πe`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+of+pi+*+e) as `8+1/(1+1/(1+1/(5+1/(1+1/(3+1/(1+1/(4+1/(10+1/(3+1/(2+1/(1+1/(5+1/(2+1/(12+1/(1+1/2)))))))))))))))`  (inspired by Jenny_mathy’s Mathematica answer).

`1` is computed as `⍴⍴⍬`: the dimensions vector (`1`) of the dimensions vector (`0`) of the empty vector (`⍬`).

Because of APL’s `÷` reciprocal operator and right-to-left grouping rules, this representation doesn’t even need parentheses. We use 6 distinct non-numeric symbols: `z+÷←⍴⍬`

---

This code should work in any APL dialect; the only important thing is that there is one where

- the answer is printed to 15 figures by default;
- the glyphs are encoded as one byte each (i.e. source code is in some custom APL codepage, not UTF-8).

Graham reports that [APL+Win](http://www.apl2000.com/) fits the bill.

Comment: Well, this works in Dyalog APL which [TIO supports](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtgmGZiAmkFFVpQ1Hh7cjMKoIggljI2lDKIVJYRiCWwtIHOQMbRD5qHcLGK35/x8A)! (note how I put `⎕←` to show the output, don't count that)

Comment: Also, can you please specify what APL dialect you're using? If you're using Dyalog, then you have a precision of 9 decimals, not 15. If you're using ngn/apl, then you should count the bytes in Unicode.

Comment: Hm… There are enough APL implementations out there that I’d expect one of them to support both an APL SBCS and 15-digit precision by default. I’ll wait for Adám to chime in!

Comment: This works in my APL+WIN which is not Unicode and produces the answer `8.539734222673568`

Comment: Further to the above I would be surprised if the precision in Dyalog is limited to 9 decimals. In APL+WIN it is controlled via `⎕PP` which by default is 10 but can be set up to 17. In APLX again the default is 10 max 15.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 199 bytes, Score = 199*(3*10+22)/11 = 940.73

```
h=g(\left\{\right\}+\left\{\right\})\int_{-\left\{\right\}}^{\left\{\right\}}\sqrt{\left\{\right\}-x^{\left\{\right\}+\left\{\right\}}}dx
\int_{\left\{\right\}}^{g}\left\{\right\}/xdx~\left\{\right\}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rs5sev9wif) Stores the result in variable `h`.

Calculates the exact values of \$\pi\$ and \$e\$ using integrals, and multiplies them together. This should theoretically yield a perfect score of 0, but Desmos only displays values to a precision of 11 decimal digits. Also, this code does not use the characters `0123456789`, instead opting for strings of `\left\{\right\}`, which are condition-less piecewise functions that evaluate to 1.

Equivalent equations:

\$h=2g\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx\$ (\$e\$ * area of circle with radius 1)

\$\int_{1}^{g}\frac{1}{x}dx\sim1\$ (\$e\$ is the unique positive real value of \$c\$ such that \$\int_{1}^{c}\frac{1}{x}dx=1\$; the \$\sim\$ tells Desmos that the equation is a regression, and therefore needs to solve for g)

Comment: [51.81818 score](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zfwqwis1u7), there is definitely room for more improvement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>116 * 39 / 14 ≈ 323.14</s> 114 * 39 / 14 ≈ 317.57

```swift
print(2+2+2+2+1/(1+1/(1+1/(2+2+1+1/(1+1/(2+1+1/(1+1/(2+2+1/(12+1/(2+1+1/(2+1/(1+1/(2+2+1+1/(2+1/12.2))))))))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/oCgzr0TDSBsCDfU1DOEEWACJhyYDZBshSRhh6gMJGRrpGWmigP//AQ)

Uses a continued fraction to approximate π*e to 14 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>22*73/11=146</s> <s>22*72/11=144</s> <s>23*53/11</s> 22*39/11=78

```
1⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺⁺^ř⁻Đ!⇹1⁺*⁺‼/Ʃ1⁺*1⁺⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺*ř⁻!⅟Ʃ*
```

Uses approximations for π and e, respectively.

Per the codepage (which is in the interpreter2 file), each character is one byte.

Explanation (stuff in brackets is what is used from the stack):

```
1⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺⁺^ř⁻Đ!⇹1⁺*⁺‼/Ʃ1⁺*           makes π

1⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺⁺^         makes 64
(64)ř             makes a list [1,2,...,64]
([1,...,64])⁻     subtracts one from each element in the list
([0,...,63])Đ     duplicates list (on top of stack twice)
([0,...,63])!     performs element-wise factorial
([...],[...])⇹    swaps top two items on the stack
([...])1⁺*⁺       doubles all values in list and adds one
([...])‼          element-wise double factorial
([...],[...])/    divides element-wise
([...])Ʃ          sums all elements in the list (approximately π/2)
(π/2)1⁺*          doubles (yields π)

1⁺⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺*ř⁻!⅟Ʃ

1⁺⁺1⁺⁺⁺⁺*         makes 15
         ř⁻       makes a list [0,1,...,14]
           !      Takes the factorial of each element in the list
            ⅟     Finds the multiplicative inverse of each element
             Ʃ    Sums the list (e)

(π,e)*              multiplies
                    (implicit print)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8FHjLhBGRnFHZz5q3H1kguKj9p0gOS2QcMMe/WMrwTyochRdWmAtio9a5x9bqfX/PwA)